# BeautifulSoup does not return results

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to make a **scraper** that will print out all the house events on this url:

https://iflyer.tv/en-jp/listing/events/on/2017-07-22/

But I get back no results with the above code, any idea why?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
response = requests.get("http://iflyer.tv/en-jp/listing/events/on/2017-07-22/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

results= soup.find_all('div', {"class": "genre_list"})

for result in results:
    print(result.find('HOUSE').get_text())
```

Comment: If that is supposed to look for `div` elements with the class `genre_list`, “no results” is the only correct result, because your input HTML does not contain a single such element.

Comment: When I inspect the page I see it though. How would you write it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not looking for the right elements. You'll need to start with looking for a `div` that has a class `holdevents`. You then look for the `dl` attribute containing `House`. If found, scrape title and dates and add to a list.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
response = requests.get("http://iflyer.tv/en-jp/listing/events/on/2017-07-22/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
events = soup.find_all('div', {"class": "holdevent"})

house_events = []
for event in events:
    genre_list = event.find('dl', {"class": "genre_list"})

    if genre_list.find(text='House'):
        title = event.find('h1', {'class' : 'title'}).a.text
        date = event.find('h1', {'class' : 'nicedate'}).text
        house_events.append((title, date))

print(house_events)
```

This will fetch you:

```
[('Tropical Disco fueled by Chandon Passion', 'SAT, 22 Jul 2017'), 
 ('West House Crossover Connection VOL.5 -Zakuro 1st Anniversary', 'SAT, 22 Jul 2017'), 
 ('SUBCULTURE', 'SAT, 22 Jul 2017')]
```

Comment: Still getting no results when I put it in.

Comment: @Orophix You didn't copy the code correctly. Look now. I've posted the full code in my program.

Comment: Thanks a lot Coldspeed!

Answer (score 0):

You should check the HTML code again. There is no div tag with class="genre_list"

Read this for more information on how to scrape using bs4:
http://web.stanford.edu/~zlotnick/TextAsData/Web_Scraping_with_Beautiful_Soup.html

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
response = requests.get("http://iflyer.tv/en-jp/listing/events/on/2017-07-22/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

results = soup.find_all('div', {"class": "holdevent"})
for result in results:
    print('event')
    print(result.find('h1', {"class": "nicedate"}).get_text())
    print(result.find('h1', {"class": "title"}).get_text())
```